# send mail as non root user

Tags: email, sendmail, tuleap

I am trying to send a mail with a non root user (also by tuleap application) but i have some trouble.

when we use a root user with command

```
  echo “TR : This is a test of sending mail” | mail -s Test <mail>
```

it return this log and my email is sent

```
Mar 10 16:59:09 localhost sendmail[11969]: t2AGx9Up011969: from=root,   size=258, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201503101659.t2AGx9Up011969@localhost.localdomain>, relay=root@localhost
Mar 10 16:59:09 localhost sendmail[11970]: t2AGx9Js011970: from=<root@localhost.localdomain>, size=521, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201503101659.t2AGx9Up011969@localhost.localdomain>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Mar 10 16:59:09 localhost sendmail[11969]: t2AGx9Up011969: to=<my mail>, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30258, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (t2AGx9Js011970 Message accepted for delivery)
Mar 10 16:59:12 localhost sendmail[11972]: STARTTLS=client, relay=<my SMTP server>, version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=OK, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits=256/256
Mar 10 16:59:15 localhost sendmail[11972]: t2AGx9Js011970: to=<my mail>, ctladdr=<root@localhost.localdomain> (0/0), delay=00:00:06, xdelay=00:00:06, mailer=relay, pri=120521, relay=<my SMTP server> [IP], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK id=1YVNUv-002ihW-JJ)
```

but when we use an other use (like codendiadm as used by tuleap) with the same command, it return this log without sending mail

```
Mar 10 16:59:53 localhost sendmail[12024]: t2AGxrhg012024: from=codendiadm, size=258, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201503101659.t2AGxrhg012024@localhost.localdomain>, relay=codendiadm@localhost
Mar 10 16:59:53 localhost sendmail[12025]: t2AGxr16012025: from=<codendiadm@localhost.localdomain>, size=556, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201503101659.t2AGxrhg012024@localhost.localdomain>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Mar 10 16:59:53 localhost sendmail[12024]: t2AGxrhg012024: to=<my mail>, ctladdr=codendiadm (495/492), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30258, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (t2AGxr16012025 Message accepted for delivery)
Mar 10 16:59:57 localhost sendmail[12027]: STARTTLS=client, relay=<my SMTP server>, version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=OK, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits=256/256
Mar 10 17:00:00 localhost sendmail[12027]: t2AGxr16012025: to=<my mail>, ctladdr=<codendiadm@localhost.localdomain> (495/492), delay=00:00:07, xdelay=00:00:07, mailer=relay, pri=120556, relay=<my SMTP server> [IP], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Mar 10 17:00:00 localhost sendmail[12027]: t2AGxr16012025: t2AH0016012027: DSN: User unknown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove sendmail and install postfix instead. And tell me if it works better this way. You'll find how to do it [here](http://doc-en.tuleap.net/en/latest/administration-guide/services.html?highlight=postfix#postfix).